# How should I present a UISearchController using a UISplitView adaptive user interface?

Tags: ios, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller, uisearchcontroller, adaptive-ui

Using a universal storyboard with an adaptive `UISplitViewController` user interface.

I want to present a search controller on the primary (master) side, using the following code (from the master view controller):

```
static NSString * const kCGISearchViewControllerID = @"SearchViewControllerID";

- (IBAction)searchButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)__unused sender {
    SearchViewController *searchResultsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kCGISearchViewControllerID];
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = searchResultsController;
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    [self presentViewController:self.searchController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

It initially appears to work correctly (regardless of the starting orientation):

[image: Landscape starts out looking ok]

Problems show up after autorotation (keyboard still visible, underlying content still dimmed, but the search bar has disappeared):

[image]

Upon rotating back to landscape, the search bar reappears, but its width is now wrong:

[image]

(I've also tried placing the search controller's `searchBar` in the `titleView`.  While the searchBar adapts correctly, the search results controller still doesn't look right.)

What am I missing to get a presented `UISearchController` to animate itself properly as the UI adapts to changing size classes?

**Update:**

Adding `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;` gets the search bar/results to appear within the primary view, but the search bar is animating *under* that navigation bar, and isn't visible.  The other issue is that the search bar height doesn't shrink, when it rotates from portrait (which has a status bar), back to landscape.

Comment: I've gotten a step closer by adding `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`  The searchBar and results controller now fit within the primary view, but the searchBar is hidden under the navigation bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Xcode version are you using? What iOS version on the simulator?
Tried that using Xcode 6, iOS 8.4 - That's all the code I used in the MasterVC:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBAction func search(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
...
}
```

It's presented within the Master and locks the orientation of the screen! The behavior might have changed since you posted your answer.

Comment: Probably.  Lots of bugs got fixed in 8.3 and 8.4.  Thanks for the report.  I shipped that app, but will keep it in mind for future apps.

Comment: Update for iOS 9.2, swift2, xcode 7.2:

Tested inside a storyboard Tableview, slight changes to the swift code

@IBAction func startSearch() { presentViewController(searchController, animated: true, completion: {})}