# UIViewController has wrong dimensions when search field keyboard is open

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, autoresizingmask

My app uses UIViewAutoresizingMasks with a scrollview and fixed bottom view but whenever the controller is presented with a search field open previously, the view shows an incorrect frame and the scrollview overlaps.
[image: Overlapping views shown here]

You can see above that the scrollview size is incorrect, which causes the overlap. It's strange that the issue only appears when a keyboard is present in the previous controller, and the autoresizing mask makes it very difficult to debug (the view frames are correct when NSLogging). There isn't much relevant code to help solve the issue but just know that I'm using scrollview resizing mask of `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`

Comment: Are you using `UISearchController` with `UISplitviewController`?  I noticed [a similar size problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27990019/how-should-i-present-a-uisearchcontroller-using-a-uisplitview-adaptive-user-inte) that disappeared when `self.definesPresentationContext = YES;`

Comment: I'm not using splitviewcontroller for this one, but I tried presentation context and there was no change

Comment: Is this on the iPhone 6?  Wondering if the narrower width is 320 and the wider is 375?

Comment: It seems to occur on many of our office test devices, including 5S and 6.

Comment: Can you post some code or share a sample project demonstrating the problem?  Someone might be able to spot the source of the issue and get you a faster answer.

Comment: The problem is that I can't really determine where in the code there is an issue, but I'll try to update the question with some more points.